# 2 variables together on an Oracle UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking over an Oracle code and I encountered this strange expression in `SET`.

```
EXEC SQL
  UPDATE inc_incident
  SET   etr_queue_time       = :o_etr_queue_time:o_etr_queue_time_ind,
```

I have never seen two variables used together like this. What does this code do? I looked on the oracle specifications for `UPDATE` and searched on the web, but could not find anything.

`etr_que_time` is of tipe `NUMBER` and `:o_etr_queue_time` and `:o_etr_queue_time_ind` are variables of type short.

Comment: You probably are looking at PRO*C code. In this case in the construct `:var1:var2`  `var1` is a host variable and `var2` is indicator variable. In the `insert` or `update` statements indicator variable regulates `NULL` assignment to the host variable. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_02prc.htm#i2000)

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov if you would properly put this into an answer, I will be happy to accept it.